# Sketch the curve $\frac{ax + b}{cx + d}$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I am working through a pure maths book out of interest. I am stuck on this problem:

If $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are positive, sketch the curve $y = \frac{ax + b}{cx + d}$ when

i) $ad - bc \lt 0$

ii)  $ad - bc = 0$

iii)  $ad - bc \gt 0$

I can work out the basics. Thus

$x$-intercept:  $f(x) = 0 \implies \frac{ax + b}{cx + d} = 0 \implies x = \frac{-b}{a}$

so intercept is $[\frac{-b}{a}, 0]$

$y$-intercept: $f(0) = \frac{b}{d}$ at point $[0,\frac{b}{d}]$

horizontal asymptote: $\frac{a}{c}$

vertical asymptote: $cx + d = 0 \implies x = \frac{-d}{c}$

I can also see that $\frac{ax + b}{cx + d} = \frac{a}{c}\left(1 + \frac{\frac{b}{a}-\frac{d}{c}}{x + \frac{d}{c}}\right)$

but I cannot put all this together to see how one could sketch the graphs except in one case: where $ad -bc = 0$ because then $\frac{b}{a}-\frac{d}{c} = 0$ and the graph will be a horizontal line equal to $\frac{a}{c}$

I think not knowing the actual magnitudes makes it difficult for me to visualise.

Comment: You can visualize it first for some examples of $a,b,c,d$ and then see how this depends on the sign of the determinant $ad-bc$.

Comment: Perhaps $$ad-bc=a(cx+d)-c(ax+b)$$ might help

Comment: Based on @Tavish answer below, and for ease of curve sketching, also notice the asymptotes at $y = \frac{a}{c}$ and $x=\frac{-d}{c}$, even though it was implied in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $c \not=0$, you can write $$y = \frac ac + \frac{bc-ad}{c^2(x+\frac dc)}$$

so $y$ is not defined when $x=-\frac dc$ and

- if $ad=bc$ you have $y$ otherwise being constant $\frac ac$
- if $ad > bc$ you have a hyperbola with horizontal asymptote $y=\frac ac$ and vertical asymptote $x=-\frac dc$ using the second and fourth quadrants
- if $ad < bc$ you have a hyperbola with horizontal asymptote at $y=\frac ac$ and vertical asymptote at $x=-\frac dc$ using the first and third quadrants

Meanwhile if $c=0$ and $d \not=0$, you have the straight line $y=\frac ad x+\frac bd$, with the slope affected by the sign of $\frac ad$, which is equivalent to the sign of $ad-bc$

Comment: Looking at this more closely, could you explain why, if $ad >  bc$ we have a hyperbola using second and fourth quadrants and when $ad < bc$ we use first and third quadrants. I’m getting confused because whatever the sign of the top part of the equation, it could be reversed depending on the sign of x.

Comment: @Steblo If it was $y=\frac1x$ you would use the first and third quadrants and if it was  $y=-\frac1x$ you would use the second and fourth.  Everything else is scale and location

Comment: Thanks. That helps me.

Answer (score 2):

From your last observation, $$\frac{ax+b}{cx+d} =\frac 1c \left( a +\frac{bc-ad}{cx+d} \right)$$

You can think of this as a series of transformations applied to the graph of $y=\frac 1x$.

Starting from it, first shift to the left by $d$. That gives $\frac {1}{x+d}$. Then squish parallel to the $x$ axis by a factor of $c$. This gives $\frac{1}{cx+d}$.

Now, scale along the $y$ axis by a factor of $bc-ad$ (here, the sign comes into play: if $bc-ad\lt 0$, you have to flip the graph over). Then, move the graph up by $a$ units and finally, squish down by a factor of $c$.